# Escape double quotes regular expression JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple question. How can I match any string that is not enclosed in double quotes or/and < and > characters sequences?

Example. I got this link. And I don't want to match it if it is enclosed in double quotes.

```
((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])
```

This doesn't work, by putting [^"] at the beggining and at the end:

```
([^"](https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|][^"])
```

Because links that are not enclosed in double quotes will not be matched unless they start with something else than a doule quote.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to match, and what you don't want to match.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: What is the actual problem you have? Like what are you trying to do with this.

Comment: Alright, here is a link.
www.something.com It should match.
Ont the other hand:
"www.something.com" or >www.something.com<
should not.

Comment: So `/^((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])$/`?

Comment: No, it will not work. I'm starting to think it is not possible.

Comment: uhh wait, that regex doesn't even work for urls in the first place...

Comment: It supposed to. There it is complete /\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig

Comment: I guess I have no other choice but to copy exactly as they did here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Find a regex that works for urls in the first place, then you can test the quote stuff

Comment: It does work if you prefix the urls VolosBlur cited with http:// AND  you make the regex ignore case.  And the solution Esailija suggested also works, accepting ```http://www.something.com``` but not ```"http://www.something.com"```.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to do it in a single RegEx since, as you've noticed, it's probably not going to work.

Assuming you're trying to do something like auto-linking, including optional quotes in your search, then discarding them after, would work:

```
var re = /"?(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]"?/gi;
var quoted = /^".+"$/;

var txt = 'A real link: http://www.example.com and a quoted link: "http://www.example.com".';

txt = txt.replace(re, 
            function(str) {
              if (str.match(quoted))
                return str;
              else
                return '<a href="' + str + '">' + str + '</a>';
            }
            );

$('#mydiv').html(txt);
```

A working example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/nlExh

Answer (score 0):

As Esailija suggested, surrounding your regex with ^ and $ will work.  Try this in your console.  Here's the regex matching a bare URL:

> > 'http://www.something.com'.match(/^((https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])$/i)
>
> ["http://www.something.com", "http://www.something.com", "http"]

and here it is not matching a URL embedded in double quotes or angle brackets:

> >'"http://www.something.com"'.match(/^((https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])$/i)
>
> null
>
> >'>http://www.something.com<'.match(/^((https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])$/i)
>
> null

Don't pick this answer as I'm just reiterating what Esailija suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible because this works:

```
<script>

var str='https://test.com/';
var patt=/[^"].*[^"]/g;

var result=patt.test(str);
document.write("Returned value: " +  result); 

str='"http://test.com/"';
result=patt.test(str);
document.write("<br>Returned value: " +  result);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe it's your regexp for the link that is wrong